# How to figure out encoding of this .dat file?

Tags: java, encoding

I have this .dat file that has account information stored in it, I'm trying to figure out what the encoding is (tried base64 and others but didn't really come up with any results). I'll put the .dat file contents that is encoded, could someone put me on the right track on this? Thanks.

**DAT file contents**

> .FPja1PnZkaIbETxbETwAenCXUXjZkLjAe

**Information stored:**

> username testing
>
> password tester
>
> pin nothing
>
> reward defence

Just like this - [not yet encoded information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8haSw.png)

Comment: How could we possibly know? Who knows what that software is doing to the input. What's the motivation for needing to know what's in this DAT file?

Comment: There is a "botting" client that encodes this information. I'm trying to automatically add "accounts" to the bot itself without having to put 1 by 1 manually, this is why I'm trying to figure out how is it done.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening that file with Microsoft Wor: Open file - All file types - .dat file.

It worked for me.